# Is there a way to create DbSets in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I'm testing some queries in a program using Linqpad6. This is the query I'm trying to test.

```
var context = this;
var parameters = new UserQueryParameters();

var query = context.Set<UserEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Filter(new UserQueryFilter(), parameters)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x)
            .Select(x => x.Key ?? string.Empty)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .Paginate(parameters)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When I try to run this I get the error

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'UserEntity' because this type is not
> included in the model for the context.

I then try

```
var context = this;
var parameters = new UserQueryParameters();
var query = context.Users
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Filter(new UserQueryFilter(), parameters)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x)
            .Select(x => x.Key ?? string.Empty)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .Paginate(parameters)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But that generates the error:

> The type arguments for method 'QueryExtensions.Filter<T,
> TParams>(IQueryable, IQueryFilter<T, TParams>, TParams?)' cannot be
> inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.`

This is the context I'm using:

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserEntityTypeConfiguration());
        }
```

What is the right way to format my query?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your context?

Comment: I added the db context to my post. I'm using configurations to make the tables in the databse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a `Connection`(top left) from linqpad and connect to your `dll`.

Here is the [doc](https://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) shows you how to do it.

When you are using Linqpad, you are actually inside the Context Object. Just type:

```cs
this.
```

and you can access the properties on your ObejctContext.

(also: make sure you use "C# Statement")

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add the two lines at the top of my query. I put var context = this already and I'm still having issues. I'm also using C# statements as well.

Comment: what's the issue